# FATAL ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/robots.txt"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, robots.txt

In my Heroku app, I am consistently getting the following error in my logs:

```
FATAL -- ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/robots.txt")
```

I have a robots.txt file in my Public directory of my Rails app:

```
User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
# Disallow: /
```

Why is Heroku not seeming to find this file?

Comment: why are you trying to access this `robots.txt` ?

Comment: I'm not trying to - it seems like this log just keeps popping up on Heroku.  Maybe robots are trying to access it?

Comment: is your rails app enabled to serve static assets? is there a robots.txt in the public folder?

Comment: Yes and yes. I also added the gem 'rails_12factor' but I am still getting the error.